# perl regex for complex multiline search replace

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I know there are many questions on this topic, but most are fairly trivial and
I'm unable to find a solution for my case.

I have a set of HTML files with many, many "media" items like the following,
each of which is a "paragraph", separated by "\n\n". Here is a [link to a sample file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/friendly/DDAR/master/pages/chapters/ch03.html) of the type I'm working on.

```
  <li class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="4_17-HE-assoc.png" width="250" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">Figure 4.17</h4>
      Association plot for the hair-color eye-color data. Left: marginal table, collapsed over
      gender; right: full table.
    </div>
  </li>
```

For each `<img ...>` tag, I need to find the `src="file"` value, and replace the `href="#"` on the previous line
by `href="file" class="fancybox`.  i.e., so that item will then look like

```
  <li class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="4_17-HE-assoc.png" class="fancybox">
        <img class="media-object" src="4_17-HE-assoc.png" width="250" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">Figure 4.17</h4>
      Association plot for the hair-color eye-color data. Left: marginal table, collapsed over
      gender; right: full table.
    </div>
  </li>
```

I tried the following as a one-liner, but it has no effect, i.e., it doesn't make the changes.

```
perl -pi~ -e '$/ = "";s|<a href="#">\n(\s*<img class="media object") src=(".*png")|<a class="fancybox" href="\2">\n\1 src=\2|ms' ch03.html
```

Can someone help with this? I'd be happy with a simple script that I could
use for this and modify for other similar modifications of a collection of web files.

**edit**: I'm aware of the advantages of using perl modules such as `HTML::TreeBuilder` to avoid having to parse HTML directly.  If someone
could give me a start, I could probably take it from there.

Comment: Before any other user does it: [obligatory warning to use regular expressions for html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Stop. Take a step back. Forget that you wanted to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Now [do it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+parse+html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't resist but write this one-off, super unstable, sends-me-to-parse-html-with-regex-hell sed command:

```
sed -i.bak '/<a href="#"/ {
    N
    /\n.*<img class=/ {
        s/^\( *<a href="\).*\(\n.*src="\)\([^"]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3" class="fancybox">\2\3\4/
    }
}' ch03.html
```

This looks for a line with `href="#"`, appends the next line and then substitutes the filename and `fancybox` into the `a` tag.

Diffing the result and the input file:

```
43c43
<           <a href="#">
---
>           <a href="saxony-barplot.png" class="fancybox">
55c55
<           <a href="#">
---
>           <a href="dbinom2-plot2-1.png" class="fancybox">
67c67
<           <a href="#">
---
>           <a href="dpois-xyplot2-1.png" class="fancybox">
79c79
<           <a href="#">
---
>           <a href="Fed0-plots2-1.png" class="fancybox">
```

Comment: I am always ambivalent when someone does this - because whilst it's technically correct, and thus doesn't really deserve a downvote, neither do I think I could in all conscience recommend someone actually use it.

Comment: However, it does **exactly** what I asked for, and doesn't mess up the formatting of the rest of the file as does the `XML::LibXML` solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $qfn = 'ch03.html';

my $in_qfn = $qfn . "~";
my $out_qfn = $qfn;
rename($qfn, $in_qfn)
   or die("Can't rename \"qfn\": $!\n");

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_html_file($in_qfn);

for my $a_node ($doc->findnodes('//a[@href="#"]')) {
   my ($src_node) = $a_node->findnodes('img[1]/@src')
      or next;

   $a_node->setAttribute('href', $src_node->value());
   $a_node->setAttribute('class', 'fancybox');
}
my $html = $doc->toStringHTML();
open(my $fh, '>', $out_qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");

print($fh $html);
```

Tested:

```html
$ diff -u ch03.html{~,}
--- ch03.html~  2016-01-20 12:41:30.809203040 -0800
+++ ch03.html   2016-01-20 12:41:31.009201042 -0800
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
-<div class="contents">
+<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
+<html><body><div class="contents">
 <h1 class="tocpage">Chapter 3: Fitting and Graphing Discrete Distributions</h1>
 <hr class="tocpage">
-
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <!-- prelude-inserted  -->
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <h3>Contents</h3>
     <dl class="chaptoc">
-        <dd>3.1. Introduction to discrete distributions</dd>
+<dd>3.1. Introduction to discrete distributions</dd>
         <dd>3.2. Characteristics of discrete distributions</dd>
         <dd>3.3. Fitting discrete distributions</dd>
         <dd>3.4. Diagnosing discrete distributions: Ord plots</dd>
@@ -27,8 +27,7 @@
         <dd>3.7. Chapter summary</dd>
         <dd>3.8. Lab exercises</dd>
     </dl>
-
-  </div>
+</div>
 </div>

 <!-- more-content -->
@@ -38,11 +37,10 @@
        <h3>Selected figures</h3>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../Rcode/ch03.R" role="button">view R code</a>
     <ul class="media-list">
-      <li class="media">
+<li class="media">
         <div class="media-left">
-          <a href="#">
-            <img class="media-object" src="saxony-barplot.png" width="250" alt="males in Saxony families">
-          </a>
+          <a href="saxony-barplot.png" class="fancybox">
+            <img class="media-object" src="saxony-barplot.png" width="250" alt="males in Saxony families"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
           <h4 class="media-heading">Figure 3.2</h4>
@@ -52,9 +50,8 @@

       <li class="media">
         <div class="media-left">
-          <a href="#">
-            <img class="media-object" src="dbinom2-plot2-1.png" width="250" alt="Binomial distributions">
-          </a>
+          <a href="dbinom2-plot2-1.png" class="fancybox">
+            <img class="media-object" src="dbinom2-plot2-1.png" width="250" alt="Binomial distributions"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
           <h4 class="media-heading">Figure 3.9</h4>
@@ -64,9 +61,8 @@

       <li class="media">
         <div class="media-left">
-          <a href="#">
-            <img class="media-object" src="dpois-xyplot2-1.png" width="250" alt="Poisson distributions">
-          </a>
+          <a href="dpois-xyplot2-1.png" class="fancybox">
+            <img class="media-object" src="dpois-xyplot2-1.png" width="250" alt="Poisson distributions"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
           <h4 class="media-heading">Figure 3.11</h4>
@@ -76,9 +72,8 @@

       <li class="media">
         <div class="media-left">
-          <a href="#">
-            <img class="media-object" src="Fed0-plots2-1.png" width="250" alt="Hanging rootogram">
-          </a>
+          <a href="Fed0-plots2-1.png" class="fancybox">
+            <img class="media-object" src="Fed0-plots2-1.png" width="250" alt="Hanging rootogram"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
           <h4 class="media-heading">Figure 3.15</h4>
@@ -89,9 +84,8 @@

       <li class="media">
         <div class="media-left">
-          <a href="#">
-            <img class="media-object" src="ordplot1-1.png" width="250" alt="Ord plot for the Butterfly data">
-          </a>
+          <a href="ordplot1-1.png" class="fancybox">
+            <img class="media-object" src="ordplot1-1.png" width="250" alt="Ord plot for the Butterfly data"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
           <h4 class="media-heading">Figure 3.18</h4>
@@ -100,9 +94,10 @@
         </div>
       </li>

-    </ul> <!-- media-list -->
-  </div> <!-- col-md-12 -->
+    </ul>
+<!-- media-list -->
+</div> <!-- col-md-12 -->
 <!-- footer -->
 </div>  <!-- row -->

-</div>
+</div></body></html>
```

Comment: I can see what this is trying to do, but it doesn't work for my test file and I can't see why.  In particular, the `href` and `class` attributes are not replaced in my `<a href="#">`

Comment: This code was written to solve the problem you asked, and it was tested against both the file in the question and the file to which the question links to make sure it does work. If you use a file in a different format than the one provided in the question, you'll need to adjust the code. If you adjust the file in your question to be more like your real file, and you let me know that you've done this by leaving a comment here, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help with this, and haven't changed the file format at all.  My test file, `ch03.html` was added to the original question, and is given here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/friendly/DDAR/master/pages/chapters/ch03.html

Comment: Again, it works for that file. My answer now includes the result.

Comment: OK, I accept that your answer works for you.  My perl (v5.14.2) has many modules out of date, so I'll have to upgrade them first to test.